how to get borders around windows
In your favorite search engine type: "borders around windows". Do you get any less than 1,000 hits or so? Why isn't this fixed?

The WM provides window borders; you've provided no Ubuntu product or release details; but many desktops allow you to use whichever WM you wish (some DEs are intended to be used with specific ones thus allow specific choice(s) only), and borders can be themed using any theme appropriate for your wanted WM.  You control the makeup of your system; or if you configure something incorrectly/badly; you're to blame for that too until you correct whatever went wrong (didn't work as you thought it would).
